# How to copy added value to cells in Excel Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENzEC.png)
[Expect Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvZ1o.png)

I want to copy all the input data to the right-hand cells after the user presses the 'CommandButton1'
Right now my code can copy the input but it will repeat the first input cell data (as you can see in the first picture)

This is my code that only copies the first cell values and repeats it as the output (it is wrong)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Set wks = Sheet1

Set AddNew = wks.Range("M65356").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
For i = 1 To 15
        For j = 0 To 6


    AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value = Me.Range("B2:H16").Value
        Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that your range is ok. (It is not matching with the one on the example).Try this one:

```
For i = 1 To 15
    For j = 0 To 6
        AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value2 = Cells(i + 1,j + 1).Value2
    Next j
Next i
```

If you want to just copy the information and then, delete the previous one on input area, just add:

```
For i = 1 To 15
    For j = 0 To 6
        AddNew.Offset(i, j).Value2 = Cells(i + 1,j + 1).Value2
        Cells(i + 1,j + 1).Value2 =""
    Next j
Next i
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you but with your code, it only works one time. If I press the button again it will not copy the input. How can I solve this problem? if I want the process to be repeat

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ' Don't use Integers, they are stored as Long anyway
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 1 To 15
        For j = 1 To 7
            wks.Range("M4").Cells(i, j) = wks.Range("B2").Cells(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Just set two cells (`B2` and `M4`) as "anchors" for ranges, for which you want to copy data. Then using `Cells` you can reference cells with respect to those "anchors" (it is very similair to using `Offset`).

Or you can be even more concise:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    wks.Range("B2:H18").Copy wks.Range("M4")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do have some problem. If after the user presses the button and the result appear. I want to delete the input so that the user can re-input new data. How can I write this kind of code?

Comment: @CeeSupa If answer has helped you, you should accept it by checking green check mark on the left side. If you have another question, ask it in separate post or google it :)